# ReactJS - CSSTransition - div dissapears after timeout

Tags: reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I'm rewriting my old page from PHP to ReactJS. I have problem with hiding and showing divs. I want my div *".tooltip"* to show after I click *".tooltip-act"*

Previously I had it done with jQuery but I found that in React the best way to do it is CSSTransition. I did it but something is wrong. After i click *".tooltip-act"* my *".tooltip"* shows but only for timeout length and then it disappears. I want it to stay until I change state back to false (I don't have this button made yet). Please look only on *".tooltip t-umiej"* because rest is already waiting for their turn

My React code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';
import avatar from './../../assets/images/avatar.png';

const getAge = birthDate => Math.floor((new Date() - new Date(birthDate).getTime()) / 3.15576e+10);

function Home(props) {
  const [showSkills, setShowSkills] = useState(false);
  const [showQuests, setShowQuests] = useState(false);
  const [showHistory, setShowHistory] = useState(false);
  const [showHobby, setShowHobby] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="profil-okno">
        <span className="name">{props.dane.personalia.imie} {props.dane.personalia.nazwisko}</span>
        <div className="avatar-main">
          <img src={avatar} alt="avatar" />
        </div>
        <div className="staty">
          <ul>
            <li><label>Płeć: </label>{props.dane.personalia.plec}</li>
            <li><label>Rasa: </label>{props.dane.personalia.rasa}</li>
            <li><label>Klasa: </label>{props.dane.personalia.klasa}</li>
            <li><label>Poziom (wiek): </label>{getAge(props.dane.personalia.urodziny)}</li>
            <li><label>Charakter: </label>{props.dane.personalia.charakter}</li>
            <li><label>Lokalizacja: </label>{props.dane.personalia.lokalizacja}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="odnosniki">
        <ul>
          <li>Umiejętności:<br /><span className="tooltip-act" onClick={() => setShowSkills(true)} >+ kliknij by rozwinąć</span></li>
          <li>Osiągnięcia:<br /><span className="tooltip-act" onClick={() => setShowQuests(true)} >+ kliknij by rozwinąć</span></li>
          <li>Historia:<br /><span className="tooltip-act" onClick={() => setShowHistory(true)} >+ kliknij by rozwinąć</span></li>
          <li>Hobby:<br /><span className="tooltip-act" onClick={() => setShowHobby(true)} >+ kliknij by rozwinąć</span></li>
          <span>{showSkills.toString()}</span>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <CSSTransition in={showSkills} timeout={2000} classNames="t-umiej">
        <div className="tooltip t-umiej">
          <ul>
            <li>HTML</li>
            <li>CSS</li>
            <li>jQuery</li>
            <li>Symfony</li>
            <li>PHP</li>
            <li>MySQL</li>
            <li>Git</li>
            <li>Administracja</li>
            <li>Grafika rastrowa</li>
            <li>Grafika wektorowa</li>
            <li>Język angielski</li>
            <li>Język niemiecki</li>
            <li>ReactJS</li>
          </ul>
          <p><a href="skills.php">+ WIĘCEJ</a></p>
          <span className="tooltip-hide">- kliknij by zwinąć</span>
        </div>
      </CSSTransition>
      {/* other tooltips */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

CSS(for tooltips):

```css
.tooltip-act {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #777777;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tooltip-hide {
    color: #777777;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tooltip ul {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.tooltip li {
    list-style: circle;
}

.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    min-width: 200px;
    text-align: left;
    border-style: solid;
   border-width: 45px 23px;
   -moz-border-image: url(../images/zwoj.png) 45 23 stretch;
   -webkit-border-image: url(../images/zwoj.png) 45 23 stretch;
   -o-border-image: url(../images/zwoj.png) 45 23 stretch;
   border-image: url(../images/zwoj.png) 45 23 fill stretch;
}

.t-umiej-enter {
    display: none;
}

.t-umiej-enter-active {
    display: block;
    transition: display 500ms;
}

.t-umiej-exit {
    display: block;
}

.t-umiej-exit-active {
    display: none;
    transition: display 500ms;
}
```

And my old working jQuery:

```js
var tool="";
var licznik=0;

$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".tooltip-act").on("click", function (event) {
        if (licznik==0) {
            tool=$(this).attr("tool");
            $(tool).css("bottom", $(window).height() - event.pageY - 50).css("left", event.pageX - 20);
            $(tool).slideDown();
            licznik=1;
            return false;
        } else {
            $(tool).slideUp();
            licznik=0;
        }
    });

    $(".tooltip").on("click", function () {
        $(tool).slideUp();
        licznik=0;
    });

});
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong and how to fix it.

Second question is what will be the best way to get similiar effect to my old jQuery (sliding down & up)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've figured it out. There were missing classes enter-done and exit-done in my css(they weren't used in CSSTransition documentation example). Now it looks like that and it's working.

```css
.t-umiej-enter {
    display: none;
}

.t-umiej-enter-active {
    display: block;
    transition: display 500ms;
}

.t-umiej-enter-done{
    display: block;
}

.t-umiej-exit {
    display: block;
}

.t-umiej-exit-active {
    display: none;
    transition: display 500ms;
}

.t-umiej-exit-done {
    display: none;
}
```

Topic to close.